# Why can't I exclude private posts from this query?

Tags: wp-admin, query

My WP query to fetch some custom posts should exclude private posts, but this query is returning all posts, not just public ones:

`$wp_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=listing&post_status!=private&posts_per_page=9&meta_key=location_level1_value&orderby=location_level1_value&order=ASC&paged='.$paged);`

I've also tried using post_status=-private, but that didn't work either...

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to wonder if post_status=public would successfully exclude. That way it's just targeting the public posts.

Comment: It does, except then I also include empty "Auto Draft" posts

Comment: But post_status=publish does the trick... thanks

Comment: Except that post_status=publish WILL include private posts if the user happens to be logged in.

Comment: @David actually 'post_status' => 'publish' works perfectly for me. It does exclude private posts even when logged in.Tested on older WP 4.9.15 though, not sure how it will behave on the newest releases.